# How to open "vscode" and "zsh in vscode" using terminal?(already install shell code command in path in VsCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I just want to open vscode in terminal and I already **install shell code command in path in vscode**, I **restart terminal by quitting and open** and I have my vscode **download** in Mac not in **application** cause when I move **vscode to application it won't open** and I have to move vscode to trash and redownload it again, do I have to also restart my computer?

**vscode**

1. Shift + Command + P
2. shell command install 'code' command in path

**Start with pwd in terminal**

1. pwd

**For open zsh in vscode:**

1. code ~/.zshrc
2. zsh: command not found: code

**For open vscode:**

1. code
2. zsh: command not found: code

**For check out vscode version in terminal:**

1. code -v
2. zsh: command not found: code

Answer (score 0):

Youtube search: vscode in macbook

Found this:
How to Install Visual Studio Code on Mac
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCfbi5PF1y0

Btw this is the long way, the short way is to:
Open the Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

Website:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

the reason for vscode not open cause of the data confuse which cause the vscode to not open, to solve the vscode not open when you put vscode in application, you basically have to redo the uninstall & install again, below are todo list if you are having the same problem:

step 1 uninstall and install vscode

step 2 move vscode from download to application

step 3 open vscode in launchpad

Step 4 **uninstall** & Shell Command: **Install** 'code' command in PATH command.

step 5 quit terminal and open it again

step 6 use the command line in above question to check if it work

Start with pwd in terminal:

**pwd**

code

code -v

code ~/.zshrc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi @NetLordOfData I would like to ask how to open .zshrc file in Xcode, whether you can advice.